# How to urlencode a empty array(not null but empty) in php, to pass to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS of a curl request?

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I am creating Fb messenger bot in php and using curl to interact with fb server. now for sending a file fb wants me to send request in this format

```
   `    curl  \
    -F recipient='{"id":"USER_ID"}' \
  -F message='{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"     `
```

Here you can see payload is an empty array.
What I am doing is

```
 $res['message'] = [
        'attachment' => [
          'type' => 'image',
              'payload' => [

            ]
        ]

    ]; `
```

After this I am using curl_setopt like this

```
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         curl_setopt($process,  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER , true);
        curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

But this doesn't work and I am getting

```
   {"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter message[attachment] [payload] is   required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"EaQ66DTssrV"}}
```

After some debugging I reached at the conclusion that since my attachment array is empty `http_build_query` does not take it into account.
see first  [comment here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

So my question is how to urlencode a empty array in php.

what I have tried till now

1. tried using array() and ''(single quotes) by assigning it to payload(here payload was included but was empty and fb seerver returned same error)
2. I can send other type of message successfully that does not include empty array.
3. curl command given is correct as I executed it from my shell using ssh access.
4. content type is multipart/form data.
5. I am sending data and file in a single request is it fine?
6. tried passing data without encoding - fb error recipient is empty
7. tried passing array directly to POSTFIELDS but got `{"error":{"message":"(#100) param recipient must be non-empty.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"BQ00BtZZmPF"}}`
   If there is a better way to execute this curl command in php please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Note: You can pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: hi I tried passing $arr=array( 'recipient' =>array('id'=>'id'),'message'=>array('attachment'=>array('type'=>'image','payload'=>array())),  'filedata' => '@/home/public_html/kapil/webhook/download.jpg;type=image/jpeg');  but it gave receipient cant be empty error

Comment: Any reason you are doing this yourself with cURL, instead of just using the PHP SDK …?

Comment: Actually I think I am using php SDK. I m using curl_execute to execute the statement and problem is in curl_set_opt command. I hope this is what you mean by using php sdk